# Is there any method to group pixel according to line segment in python?

Tags: python, list, image-processing, data-structures, computer-vision

I have these points:

points=[(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(1,5),(1,6),(1,7),(1,8),(1,9),(1,10),(1,11),(5,24),(5,25),(4,24)]

I am grouping pixel points based on line segment.
My code as follows:

```
def neighborspixel(node):
    return ((node[0]-1, node[1]-1), (node[0]-1, node[1]), (node[0]-1, node[1]+1), (node[0], node[1]-1), 
            (node[0], node[1]+1), (node[0]+1, node[1]-1), (node[0]+1, node[1]), (node[0]+1, node[1]+1))


points=[(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(1,5),(1,6),(1,7),(1,8),(1,9),(1,10),(1,11),(5,24),(5,25),(4,24)]
tempnodes= points.copy()
visitednode=[]
group=[]
while(len(tempnodes)>0):
    visitednode=[tempnodes.pop()]
    visitnode=visitednode[0]   
    nset=candidate_neighbors(visitnode)
    print('nset',nset)           
    print('append grp',group)     
    for i in neighborspixel(visitnode):
     
        if i in tempnodes:
            print('i',i)
            visitednode.append(i)
            tempnodes.remove(i)
    group.append(visitednode)  
         
print('group',group)
print('visited',visitednode)
```

Result I got these result :

```
group [[(4, 24), (5, 24), (5, 25)], [(1, 11), (1, 10)], [(1, 9), (1, 8)], [(1, 7), (1, 6)], [(1, 5), (1, 4)], [(1, 3), (1, 2)]]
```

Result I wanted these result :

```
 group [[(4, 24), (5, 24), (5, 25)], [(1, 11), (1, 10), (1, 9), (1, 8), (1, 7), (1, 6), (1, 5), (1, 4), (1, 3), (1, 2)]]
```

Comment: Please try and improve your question - it's really not very helpful. At the moment, it more or less says *"I have these points. I want these but I got those. Here's some uncommented code."*

Comment: I have updated question @MarkSetchell. Thanks, for your suggestion.